# 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable during war file creation in Django-Jython

Tags: django, tomcat, jython, war

I am trying to generate a war file on my local machine, so as to deploy the Django application on the web server. I am using Django-Jython for the same purpose. I am using a MySQL database and have set the CLASSPATH variable as mentioned in the documentation. The name of my Django project is "gui" and it resides in C:\

I run the following command :

> C:\gui> jython C:\gui\manage.py war --include-java-libs=C:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar

And I get the following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "C:\gui\manage.py", line
>   10, in  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 443, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 382, in execute
>           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 196, in run_from_argv
>           self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 217, in execute
>           translation.activate('en-us')
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 217, in execute
>           translation.activate('en-us')
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\utils\translation__init__.py",
>   line 105, in activate
>           return _trans.activate(language)
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py",
>   line 194, in activate
>           _active.value = translation(language)
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py",
>   line 183, in translation
>           default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
>
> File
>   "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.5.egg\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py",
>   line 161, in _fetch
>           apppath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(app.**file**), 'locale')
>
> File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\ntpath.py", line 207, in dirname
>           return split(p)[0]   File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\ntpath.py", line 164, in split
>           d, p = splitdrive(p)   File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\ntpath.py", line 119, in splitdrive
>           if p[1:2] == ':': TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: Seriously, how are we supposed to answer this question? You haven't shown any details - what command did you run, what is your project structure, what is the traceback...